# Design a Client / Server messaging system in Java

Tags: java, json, architecture, client-server

I'm trying to design a system that coordinates messages between different clients and a central server.  There are a bunch of different message types that each have different information in them. So like message header, time, message type, and actual message.  I need to pass them between the clients and the server at will.  So if the server decides that client B3 needs a message and client B1 needs a message it should be able to send it to them.  I was thinking some sort of RESTful JSON message passing system, but then I didn't know how to send a client a message from the server without the client implicitly asking for it.  Does anyone know the best way to architect this system, or can point me in the right direction?  If you need more information I will be happy to provide it.

[image: Client / Server architecture]

Comment: You can't just ask us to architect a technology.  Look at what ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ does and copy that.  Or just use ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ.

Comment: This is a technology?? I'm trying to design something system specific

Comment: Do I want to use RabbitMQ for this?

Comment: (I believe that) Jetty 8/9 has WebSockets. That may be an option.

Comment: This is probably offtopic on the SO, try [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Grammin do *not* try writing this out of the box.  You will die.  Use an existing solution.

Comment: Several questions: I see "Push vs Pull" and "Queues management". Too general for SO

Comment: @djechlin this is what we had to do - write out of the box. I am still typing so I guess I am alive :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds A LOT like queues - we have to do something very close to what you are doing right now. In the end we used google protocol buffers and JMS Messages as binary.
I think that JMS is the place to start here. There are already a lot of solutions like that - you need to adapt them. ActiveMQ is probably the 'nearest'